# Shared settings across Universal Apps. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, xaml, settings, win-universal-app, appsettings

I would like to create a set of Windows Universal Apps with each has different functionality.

However, I would like to use the same settings (account settings and app preferences) for all those apps.
Is this possible because of the isolated storage.

It would be a hassle to have to set those settings on each app individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 Apps from the same publisher can share local per-user data in the PublisherCache folder retrieved via ApplicationData.[GetPublisherCacheFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice option to proceed with.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ApplicationData.RoamingSettings.

The name of each setting can be 255 characters in length at most. Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size and each composite setting can be up to 64K bytes in size. The sync engine may limit the total size of settings and files that can roam.

var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

// Create a simple setting

roamingSettings.Values["mySetting"] = "Available Across devices";

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.asp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx)x

Comment: Is this setting not intented for one application only, but across devices. How would you prevent collision of setting names used? For clarification: I need App A to access the same settings App B uses.